# Blackberry JAVA (OS < 10) LinkedIn Integration

Tags: blackberry, oauth, linkedin-api

Application required to integrate LinkedIn in Blackberry JAVA OS .

I searched the BB support forum but did not find any library which we can directly integrate with BB.

It requires an oauth library . Does anybody know of a BB oauth library which works with LinkedIn?

Comment: I required for BB JAVA (OS < 10)

Comment: Refer http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication